# Mockito - mocking only a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, mocking, mockito

So I have following problem:

I have a class and I created three objects of it (obj1, obj2, obj3). I assigned them various values via setter-methods in my Testclass, since they will be used in a list later on.

The thing is, the class has a method, which returns a boolean, and it gets the value via SAP-Services, which of course I don't want to mock. So of course I want to use the when-method from Mockito to make sure, they return different values, because the class I want to test, sorts the files based on what they return on the method.

```
when(obj1.method()).thenReturn(true);
when(obj2.method()).thenReturn(false);
when(obj3.method()).thenReturn(true);
```

To do this, I need to mock the objects:

```
@mock
private Object obj1;
```

and in my setUp:

```
obj1 = mock(Object.class);
```

But when I do this, it won't allow me to set values for the objects.

How do I do that nonetheless, I need to fill the objects with some things, I can't leave them blank. It's only that there's no other way to set the return-value of the method than to mock the object..

Comment: Post the code that you want to test.

Comment: Mock is used to verify the behavior, why would you need to set values if you can control the return value.

Comment: That's my whole problem, I don't want to test the behaviour of this method, I just want to ensure, that when it gets called in my class, I want to test, it will return these values, so my class can sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mock only some methods of the object, you can use @Spy
The method should be mocked a bit differently in this case though
doReturn(true).when(obj1).method();

See http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html for more info

Answer (score 1):

Never use `@Mock obj1` and `obj1 = mock(Object.class);` together... they are both doing the same thing and one is overriding the other.

If you use `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` and `@Mock` you don't need `mock(...)` (most of the time).

Also, I doubt that `obj1` should be of type Object, I'm guessing it should be a more specific interface type.